# Convert HTML5 to Flash

Tags: flash, html, video, html5-video, impress.js

I am using impress.js extensively to create a lot of HTML5 presentations.  These presentations need to be displayed on touch-screen kiosks.  Unfortunately, the vendor handling the kiosks has said that only Flash content can be displayed on these kiosks.

Is there a work-around for this (changing vendor is ruled out, as they control most kiosks here)?  How do I convert HTML5 to Flash, without losing the effects my presentations have?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the only way is to port it (rewrite application into Flash).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render HTML5 `<canvas>` animation to a video file (h264, WMV, pick your favorite) on server-side. Legacy browsers can playback then this video.

We have developed proprietary technology to address this need.

See the old question

- [Rendering HTML5 animation server-side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805850/rendering-html5-animation-server-side)

Answer (score 0):

If you know php, then using the following documentation you can convert files like .jpg, .pdf etc files to .swf.
To do this, follow these steps:

1) Download phpswfTools by composer

https://php-swftools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

```
 {
      "require": {
          "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "master"
     }
   }
```

2) Add this file "vendor/autoload.php" in your library

```
 <?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

3) Then use the following code to convert PDF to SWF

```
     <?php

    use SwfTools\PDFFile;
    use SwfTools\Configuration;

    $PDF = new PDFFile('file.pdf');
    /* Will autodetect pdf2swf location */
    $PDF->toSwf('destination.swf');

    $PDF = new PDFFile('file.pdf',new  Configuration('pdf2swf'=>'/my/custom/path/to/pdf2swf'));
   /* Will use /my/custom/path/to/pdf2swf */
   $PDF->toSwf('destination.swf');
```

Comment: an answer should hold more then just, see this link for solve your issue. As it stands now your answer should be a comment. If you can explain how to solve it in your answer and reference to the link it will be fine.