# HTML5 check if the content of a <video> remained the same for a second.

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, keynote, iwork

Since the export to powerpoint and online icloud option for Keynote aren't sufficient for me i wanted to use the export to quicktime option to show my presentation.

Now I want to use JavaScript and the HTML5 video tag, to play the video on keydown event and whenever the content of the playing video remains the same for a second (amount of time between animation or next slide) pause the video.

My question is how would I check if the content of the playing video remained the same for a second?

Comment: I'm not criticising the question, but may I ask you what you find insufficient about the options you've dismissed? Simply for curiosity.

Comment: You can draw the video onto a canvas and get pixel by pixel that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130475/get-raw-pixel-data-from-html5-video - probably laggy as..

Comment: Why bother?  If you're using the right video codec and your content on-screen doesn't change, the video codec will use almost zero bandwidth.  Why not just export images?  Why not export to one of the many existing powerpoint web-based players?  It sounds like you are trying to do the hardest thing possible that will have the least success.  Don't make a hackjob method if you don't have to.

Comment: Are you trying to continuously keep checking the content of the video while is is playing? For e.g. maintain a bitmap of the video buffer and keep checking and updating it with the current pixels on the screen? Sounds like that might be quite a task.

Comment: @Brad Presentations often have animations so aren't just static images - in my experience all 'powerpoint web-based players' have serious problems and often the easiest solution is video unfortunately (meaning you get no slide controls).

Comment: @source.rar i thought about using a second <video> playing 1 second behind to check.