# how to run HTML5/JS code without client side?

Tags: jquery, html, ffmpeg, html5-canvas, css-animations

I need to create some animations using HTML5 canvas. And then need to convert it to video by capturing each frame.

My problem is to run the HTML5/JS code on server side without any client(browser). Is it possible? Can I just run it without actually rendering on a browser and still produce all animations?

TIA

Comment: Maybe in a [headless browser](https://www.google.tt/search?q=headless+browser&oq=headless+browser&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: This exact question has been asked here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805850/rendering-html5-animation-server-side
with answers provided

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)? It is a headless Javascript library. Once I worked on a project where I had to load an web page, capture the screenshot and save as an image file (.png). Everything was done using PhantomJs without actually loading the page on any browser.

Comment: I would also endorse PhantomJS. Think of PhantomJS as a Webkit browser without the browser display--all the Html, CSS & JS are functional.